# GeoTools change buffer style

Tags: buffer, geotools

Is it somehow possible to change the buffer style of the build in GeoTools buffer() function? Or is there a User Definded Function for that? I just saw a different buffer function where one could define the number of segments.

I need something similar to the options QGIS has. I want to define the "End cap style" and the "join style". At the moment GeoTools creates the buffers with round corners. But when I for example buffer a triangle I want it to remain a triangle just with a greater area.

Answer (score 2):

Ok sorry I asked. Right after posting I stumbled across the answer ... Silly me ..
Here is the code one can use:

```
int nSegments = 5;
int cap = BufferParameters.CAP_FLAT;
int join = BufferParameters.JOIN_MITRE;

BufferParameters bufferParam = new BufferParameters(nSegments, cap, join, BufferParameters.DEFAULT_MITRE_LIMIT);

BufferOp ops = new BufferOp(transformedGeometry, bufferParam);
Geometry bufferedtransformedGeometry = ops.getResultGeometry(distance);
```

using

```
import org.locationtech.jts.operation.buffer.BufferOp;
import org.locationtech.jts.operation.buffer.BufferParameters;
```

**EDIT**

For anyone interested in the differences between the above and a simple buffer, here is a picture.

[image]