Buffer and dissolve layer with GeoTools
I have layer with polyline type, while I want to buffer them and dissolve the result.
In QGIS, the buffer support Dissolve cap join  option like this:

While with GeoTools I can only make the buffer like this:
SimpleFeatureSource source = store.getFeatureSource("line");
SimpleFeatureCollection sfc = new BufferFeatureCollection().execute(source.getFeatures(),0.000001,null);
     

I can not found the configuration for Dissolve cap join.
Does GeoTools support that or not?

This question is similar to: GeoTools change buffer style. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I am using BufferFeatureCollection for batch buffering the whole layer.

GeoTools has also a more advanced buffer function that is using JTS. See the usage from
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/312064/30184.
The options of the JTS buffer are documented in https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#buffer-double-int-int- It seems that you want to create round end caps that is also the default, and the only one that BufferFeatureCollection supports.
Buffer function creates a buffered geometry for each source geometry. The "dissolve result" option in QGIS is actually another function that is processing the whole layer that is first created with buffer. User interface hides that it is a two-step process from the user. It is possible to do the same also with GeoTools by combining the buffered geometries. Have a look at the documentation https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jts/combine.html
